# How to display this 2d array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been trying to display this array as a grid of 6X6 form but it is appearing in a straight line. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

I need it to show as

a s c g s f

g g j n j s

h v i e m a

Please enlighten me thanks!

Code:

```
using namespace std;

int generateRand() 
{ return rand() % 9000 + 1000; }

void arraynumbers()
{
    int board[ 6 ][ 6 ];
    int cols = 6;
    int rows = 6;

    srand( (unsigned) time( NULL ) );

    for ( int b = 0; b < rows; b++ )
    {
        for ( int a = 0; a < cols; a++ )
        {
            cout << char( 218 );

            for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
            {
                cout << char( 196 );
            }

            cout << char( 191 ) << endl;
            cout << char( 179 ) << generateRand() << char( 179 ) << endl;
            cout << char( 192 );

            for ( int k = 0; k < 4; k++ )
            {
                cout << char( 196 );
            }

            cout << char( 217 ) << " " << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    arraynumbers();
    cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: If you want output to start on a new line, you print - wait for it - a newline character, also known as `'\n'`

Comment: Could you please properly indent your code? It is a **headache** to look at

Comment: made it better, but not a new line instead displaying it like a grid of 6 by 6 boxes with numerals in them..